# Java applet not loading on Mac, Safari or Chrome

Tags: java, applet

Im just getting started with Java applets. And while I have been creating them and running them in Eclipse just fine, when I go to open the HTML page in Safari or Chrome on a Mac, the applet will not load. Im running java 8, the latest update.

Am I missing something here? 
Here is the java and html file that I came using.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;


public class JavaTest extends Applet
{
 public void paint( Graphics screen )
 {
    Font f = new Font( "TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC, 36 );
    screen.setFont( f );
    Color c = new Color( 40, 80, 120 );
    screen.setColor( c );
    screen.drawString( "Java Rocks!!", 100, 60 );
 }
}
```

Here is the HTML file, in same file as java file, with file name index.html.

```
<HTML>

<APPLET width=300 height=300 code="JavaTest.class"> 
</APPLET>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try out my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `<applet>` tag is obsolete in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#the-applet-element). Try replacing it with the `<embed>` tag. Try this:

```
<embed id="my-applet"
       type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
       width="300" 
       height="300" 
       archive="my-applet.jar"
       code="my.package.myclass"
       pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"
       myParam="my parameters" />
```

Notice that you have to modify the `archive` and `code` attributes to match that in your project.